# Batch script to take backup of all *.c and *.h files

Tags: shell, scripting, batch-file, dos

I am new to MS batch programing.

I want to copy files with matching regex to destination with same directory structure. If I use dir /b /s, I get full path of source then how can I get the relative path from source path?

I want DOS based batch script equivalent of something like this in bash script,

```
file_list=`find ./abc/test -name "*.c"`
for file_n in $file_list
do
    cp $file_n $targetdir/$file_n
done
```

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for superuser.com

Comment: please let me know the answer before closing this question. It will be really helpful to me.

Also, I thought its programming related question so asked here.

Comment: If it's closed as moved, there will be a link here which you can follow to superuser.com where other people may add answers.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking source control is more appropriate than taking backups if source files...

Comment: +1 Cannot agree more.  Assuming that the repository is on a different drive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way, is to simply use `pushd/popd`:

```
pushd abs/test
file_list=`find . -name "*.[ch]"`
for file_n in $file_list
do
    cp $file_n $targetdir/$file_n
done
popd
```

Comment: I want DOS based batch script equivalent of this. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tar with a pipe to copy the directory hierarchy properly:

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' -exec tar cf - '{}' '+' | tar xf - -C $targetdir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tar cvf backup-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar `find . -name "*.[ch]" -print`
```

will create a dated tar file of the required files. That's possibly easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

with batch,

```
@echo off
for /F %%A in ('dir /b/s c:\test\*.c c:\test\*.h') do (
  echo copy "%%A" c:\destination
)
```

remove the echo to actual copy

Comment: @ghostdog74 ... it does not recreate the directory structure. Thats my actually problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `robocopy` command will probably do what you want, but you didn't say what version of Windows you have (or is it really DOS rather than CMD?).

```
robocopy -s sourcedir destdir *.c *.h
```

or `xcopy` might work for you

```
xcopy /s *.c \destdir\
xcopy /s *.h \destdir\
```